# How to map JSON to TypeScript objects with calculated properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a fairly standard service returning some JSON.

An example return body could be:

```
[{ a: 1, b: 2 }]
```

I want to map this to instances of the following Typescript class:

```
export class MyClass {
  a: number;
  b: number;

  get c() : number {
      return this.a + this.b;
  }
}
```

I incorrectly assumed `HttpClient.get` would do exactly this, but while it does map it to compatible objects, they are missing the property.

```
this.http.get<MyClass[]>('http://www.example.com/endpoint');
```

Is there a way to get Angular to do this automatically, or do I need to a manual mapping like this:

```
.map(data => {
    const results : MyClass[];
    for(const d of data) {
        const mc = new MyClass();
        mc.a = d.a;
        mc.b = d.b;
        results.push(mc);
    }
    return results;
});
```

It works, but it is tedious code to write and can easily create dependencies I do not want in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has no access to the generic type arguments like that. It's just a compiler annotation. In cases of JSON mapping, i tend to write a static parse function in the target class and then just `map` the plain object over that.

If you do not mangle class names and properties, you can use key iteration to automatically map properties to some degree (only works well for simple types without much additional code).

Comment: Ah.. Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer none the less, thanks :) (I'll accept later when I'm allowed to)

Comment: In simple cases like this, [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) actually gets you there already: `Object.assign(new MyClass(), d)`.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can create some parse function like

```
const mapJsonToObject = Type => obj => Object.assign( new Type(), obj );
```

And use it like

```
...
.map( data => mapJsonToObject(MyClass) )
...
```

2) In other way, you can assign all properties in class constructor

```
export class MyClass {
  a: number;
  b: number;

  constructor(obj: MyClass) {
    Object.assign( this, obj );
  }

  get c() : number {
      return this.a + this.b;
  }
}
```

And in `map` simply create new entity of `MyClass`

```
...
.map( data => new MyClass( data as MyClass ) )
...
```

Comment: @H.B. beat you to it, but that is a much better solution for simple cases, thanks.